# Passing wildcard values in params in snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to clean a data pipeline by using `snakemake`. It looks like wildcards are what I need but I don't manage to make it work in `params`

My function needs a parameter that depends on the wildcard value. For instance, let's say
it depends on `sample` that can either be `A` or `B`.

I tried the following (my example is more complicated but this is basically what I am trying to do) :

```py
sample = ["A","B"]

import pandas as pd

def dummy_example(sample):
    return pd.DataFrame({"values": [0,1], "sample": sample})

rule all:
    input:
        "mybucket/sample_{sample}.csv"

rule testing_wildcards:
    output:
        newfile="mybucket/sample_{sample}.csv"
    params:
        additional="{sample}"
    run:
        df = dummy_example(params.additional)
        df.to_csv(output.newfile, index = False)
```

which gives me the following error:

> Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
> 'sample'

I followed the doc and put `expand` in `output` section.
For the `params`, it looked like [this section](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#non-file-parameters-for-rules) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371733/using-wildcards-in-params) was giving me everything needed

```py
sample_list = ["A","B"]

import pandas as pd
import re

def dummy_example(sample):
    return pd.DataFrame({"values": [0,1], "sample": sample})
    
def get_wildcard_from_output(output):
    return re.search(r'sample_(.*?).csv', output).group(1)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("sample_{sample}.csv", sample = sample_list)

rule testing_wildcards:
    output:
        newfile=expand("sample_{sample}.csv", sample = sample_list)
    params:
        additional=lambda wildcards, output: get_wildcard_from_output(output)
    run:
        print(params.additional)
        df = dummy_example(params.additional)
        df.to_csv(output.newfile, index = False)
```

> InputFunctionException in line 16 of /home/jovyan/work/Snakefile:
> Error:
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
> Wildcards:

Is there some way to catch the value of the wildcard in params to apply the value in `run` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are trying to get the `sample` wildcard to use as a parameter in your script.

The `wc` variable is an instance of [`snakemake.io.Wildcards`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference/internal/snakemake.html#snakemake.io.Wildcards) which is a [`snakemake.io.Namedlist`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference/internal/snakemake.html#snakemake.io.Namedlist).
You can call `.get(key)` on these objects, so we can use a `lambda` function to generate the params.

`samples_from_wc=lambda wc: wc.get("sample")` and use this in the run/shell as `params.samples_from_wc`.

```py
sample_list = ["A","B"]

import pandas as pd

def dummy_data(sample):
    return pd.DataFrame({"values": [0, 1], "sample": sample})

rule all:
    input: expand("sample_{sample}.csv", sample=sample_list)

rule testing_wildcards:
    output:
        newfile="sample_{sample}.csv"
    params:
        samples_from_wc=lambda wc: wc.get("sample")
    run:
        # Load input
        df = dummy_data(params.samples_from_wc)
        # Write output
        df.to_csv(output.newfile, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it worked ! To check if I have understood, `expand` should be on `all` rule, simplifying the reference to `sample` values in output (`{sample}`) or in other part of the script (by using `wc` instance) : that's right ?

Comment: Expand is typically on `rule all` unless, for example, you are aggregating everything in a final step then it might be on the second-to-last rule. And yes, I think you understand, snakemake will add the `sample` value for inputs/outputs, but if you need to use the value directly you need to get it from the wildcards.